# Flexbox equal height issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a list with items each containing text and an image. I'm using flexbox to align the text and the image.

However, I would like the height of the text element (`.list-content`) to define the height of the image element (`.list-img`), but I can't make it work.

```css
    .advanced-list {
      list-style: none;
      width: 85%;
    }
    
    .advanced-list li {
      display: flex;
      min-height: 80px;
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    
    .advanced-list li .list-img {
      display: block;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      flex: 1 0 33%;
    }
    
    .advanced-list li .list-img img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .advanced-list li .list-content {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .advanced-list li .list-content .list-header {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    
    .advanced-list li .advanced-link {
      display: flex;
      color: #252525;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .advanced-list li .advanced-link:hover {
      background-color: #e7e6e6;
    }
    
    .advanced-list li + li {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="advanced-list">
      <li>
        <div class="list-content">
          <h4 class="list-header">List item without link</h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus placerat augue diam, id ornare neque mollis eu. Vivamus semper diam urna, in maximus felis sollicitudin eget. Vivamus sed mi at nunc condimentum placerat.
        </div>
        <div class="list-img">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/250x125?text=250x125" alt="Img title">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="advanced-link">
          <div class="list-content">
            <h4 class="list-header">List item with link</h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus placerat augue diam, id ornare neque mollis eu. Vivamus semper diam urna, in maximus felis sollicitudin eget. Vivamus sed mi at nunc condimentum placerat. Aenean eget gravida sem.
            Vestibulum mollis eros non fermentum rhoncus.
          </div>
          <div class="list-img">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/250x125?text=250x125" alt="Img title">
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Note that sometimes there can be an `<a>` element wrapping the content.
Also, the image should fill up 33% of the width of the list item.

See [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/y5pxkbn1/1/).

Comment: Maybe this is what you want !... http://jsfiddle.net/y5pxkbn1/2/

Comment: What should happen with the image when it won't fit? ...cover and get clipped, contain and not get clipped, stretch ?

Comment: @Chiller, actually, I would like to shrink to image if the there's only a little content, so it's not exactly what I'm after.

Comment: @LGSon: Cover and get clipped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your image should be based on the height of the text and be 33% wide, combine `background-image` with `background-size: cover`.

Here I simply removed the `img` and added the image source to the `list-img` element in the markup using a inline style, though you can of course also put the image path in the external CSS.

Another option would be to use `object-fit` on the `img`, thought it has less browser support than `background-image`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5pxkbn1/3/)

Stack snippet

```css
.advanced-list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 85%;
}

.advanced-list li {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 80px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.advanced-list li .list-img {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.advanced-list li .list-content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.advanced-list li .list-content .list-header {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.advanced-list li .advanced-link {
  display: flex;
  color: #252525;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.advanced-list li .advanced-link:hover {
  background-color: #e7e6e6;
}

.advanced-list li + li {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="advanced-list">
  <li>
    <div class="list-content">
      <h4 class="list-header">List item without link</h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus placerat augue diam, id ornare neque mollis eu.
    </div>
    <div class="list-img" style="background-image: url(https://placehold.it/250x125?text=250x125)">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="advanced-link">
      <div class="list-content">
        <h4 class="list-header">List item with link</h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus placerat augue diam, id ornare neque mollis eu. Vivamus semper diam urna, in maximus felis sollicitudin eget. Vivamus sed mi at nunc condimentum placerat. Aenean eget gravida sem.
        Vestibulum mollis eros non fermentum rhoncus.
      </div>
      <div class="list-img" style="background-image: url(https://placehold.it/250x125?text=250x125)">
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Will give it a try. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Meek Let me know if you run into trouble and I'll try to help

Answer (score 1):

Give `height: 100%` to the `img` tag.
Hope this will help you.

See this:
http://jsfiddle.net/y5pxkbn1/4

Comment: There is a reason one need to add code if one add external links to fiddle, codepen, etc., an answer should contain the essential part of the code within the answer itself, as if that external link dies, so does the value of the answer. Don't circumvent SO policy by doing like that, post a proper answer.